# Set div height to was it was before changing it manually

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have made an example: http://jsfiddle.net/YfV7G/4/

It's a div like this

```
<div id="container">
    <h2>The header</h2>
    <a href="#">One of dynamic ammount of links</a>
    <a href="#">One of dynamic ammount of links</a>
    <a href="#">One of dynamic ammount of links</a>
    <a href="#">One of dynamic ammount of links</a>
    <a href="#">One of dynamic ammount of links</a>
</div>
```

That I change the height of by:

```
$('#container').animate({
    height: '5px'
}, 1000, null);​
```

Css is `overflow:hidden`

I change the height to only show the topmost part of a div.

But what should I set the height to to get it back and show the full content?

One way I could think of myself is to save it before making it smaller. Is there another option?
(That way wont for if there is content changes after the height is saved, which it might)

Comment: What is the role of `onclick="alert('lol')"`?

Comment: Nothing, that's prolly just from previously, when I tried it. Use http://jsfiddle.net/YfV7G/4/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store the initial height in a rel attribute and retrieve it later. Something like this:

```
var container = $("#container");

container.attr('rel', container.height()).animate({
    height: '40px'
}, 1000, null);

container.hover(
  function() {
    $(this).height(container.attr('rel'));
  },
  function() {
    $(this).animate({
      height: '40px'
    }, 1000, null);
  }
);
```

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/kvZ26/

**EDIT:**
This is the updated answer which should work with dynamically generated content. Depending on your styling you might need to use `.outerHeight()` when retrieving the value.

```
var container = $("#container");

container.attr('rel', container.height()).animate({
    height: '40px'
}, 1000, null);

container.hover(
  function() {
    var height = $("#container > h2").height() + ($("#container > a").height() * $("#container > a").length);
    $(this).height(height);
  },
  function() {
    $(this).animate({
      height: '40px'
    }, 1000, null);
  }
);
```

(You might want to tweak it so you don't need to duplicate the container id).

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/xDCsY/1/

Comment: The problem with this, is (as I said in my post) it wont work in this case: http://jsfiddle.net/kvZ26/2/ (when more stuff is added to the container)

Comment: Sorry. I didn't realize the list would change dynamically without page load. In that case, may I suggest that you grab the height of each element inside and set it. Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/xDCsY/

Comment: Dont rellay see your jsfiddle working.. But guess thats the best idea so far!

Comment: Hm, looks like I failed to save the fiddle. Here is what I meant: http://jsfiddle.net/xDCsY/1/

Answer (score 2):

Use the value `auto` for the `height`

```
$('#container').height( 'auto' );
```

Comment: Someone proposed that before. But it wont work if the height is set manually anytime before it's set to auto.

Answer (score 2):

I found one way I can get the same effect, by using jQuerys `slideUp()` and `slideDown()`
instead of doing it "manually".

Then it'll be something like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/YfV7G/9/

Answer (score -1):

```
height:initial
overflow: visible
```

upd: add 'show' button to your example, http://jsfiddle.net/YfV7G/6/

Comment: `initial` isn't a valid value for `height`